# Display character and integer to string with conditional in java

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements

I think I'm missing something fundamental. I'm trying to display a character and an integer into a string while using a conditional.

Code:

```
public String display()
{
   String Term = Character.toString(B) + Integer.toString(C);
   int length = Term.length();
   if (length == 1) {
       Term = Character.toString(B);
   }
   if (length > 1) {
       Term = Character.toString(B) + Integer.toString(C);
   }
   return Term;
}

public char getB()
{return B;
}

public int getC()
{return C;
}
```

Where `B` is a character and `C` is an integer.  So the error that keeps coming up looks like this:

> A.display() should return "A" expected: < A [] > but was: < A[1] >

I've been trying to fix this for hours now and to no avail. How should I go about fixing this error? Thanks.

Comment: the code you posted is not related with the error: ***A.display() should return "A" expected: < A [] > but was: < A[1] >***

Comment: How is it unrelated? I forgot to mention that A was a test code that specifically targets this bit of code.

Comment: Can you include the whole method?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to java and I'm not too sure if this is what you meant by including the whole method?

Answer (score 0):

First, this code won't run as it is because you should declare your character and integer variables. 
Plus, you're getter-methods are used in case you have another interfering class with this class.
And if you want a code for such a problem don't hesitate to ask me.